# Create authentication form using a Web Component

Tags: ionic-framework, facebook-login, web-component, google-signin, stenciljs

I'm thinking about using [StencilsJS](https://stenciljs.com/) for creating a complete login/registration form. Including features like Google and Facebook logins.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have web component which can be configurable (CSS and authentication settings) and that can be imported in any web project to be used.

Is it possible with StencilJS to create such web components with that many functionalities? Is that a good idea or not?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible with StencilJS to create such web components with that many functionalities?

Yes, it is possible to use StencilJS to create web components **as part of this solution**.

However, your solution will require more than just web components - for example, federated login (via Facebook, Google etc) requires support from the back-end of your web application as well as just a button on the login screen. It's difficult to advise any further without more information.

> Is that a good idea or not?

Sure! StencilJS is designed to create re-usable web components that don't need to be distributed alongside any other library.

*Note: If this answer is brief, it is because your question is also brief and unspecific*